# VB .net: SetDatabaseProviderFactory is not a member of DatabaseFactory

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am trying tp upgrade one of our old MVC application and that has exception handler library in VB. net built using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. Now I am trying to compile the exception handler library and getting the error says SetDatabaseProviderFactory is not a member of DatabaseFactory. I am not sure why this is missing now? Is the SetDatabaseProviderFactory a method present in past as a member of DatabaseFactory class and removed in later versions.

Thank you,
Muthukumar.J

Nothing seems to be working here because of this problem

Comment: What version of EL are you building against? Based on what I can see, looking at the old documentation, it is there in v6 but not in v5 or earlier.